# How to prevent Assets files from reverse engineering in APK

Tags: java, android, database, apk, assets

I've a question related to Data security in Android development. Right now i am working in an application where i need to keep an existing database in assets folder so App can copy it in to the internal writable location to avoid the large database download from server during first time installation. But unfortunately using APK decompiling tool one can view the files in assets folder included this database file. Is there a way to prevent my assets-files from being decompiled so Data security can be assured in my application. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the question is necessarily a duplicate, although maybe not formed in the best way. You want to secure the data inside your database and not the database file itself. There are several tools that encrypt sqlite databases like https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no . there will always be some way where a potential hacker can do it's tricks though you can make it harder by using some 'encryption' schemes mean you can encrypt your data with some special key,then with the `key` you can `encode` and `decode` your data so better place to keep things more secure is `nactive libs` means you using `native`(c,c++) code which should contain your sensitive data  and generate `libs`, by doing this you are adding an another layer of encryption because reverse engineered native form of native libs are quite hard to read.