# Hardcoding user name and password in android app

Tags: android

I am creating an App and i want to store username and password in app itself. The username password is not entered by user. The credentials is common for everyone. I want to save the username and password in app code itself. What is the secure method to save in android?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SharedPreference` to store data permanently in the `Android` app.

In your `Activity`,

```
    //get the sharedPrefs
    val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return

    //store the data in sharedPrefs file
    with (sharedPref.edit()) {
        putString("Some_key_user_name",userNameText)
        commit()
    }

   //read the stored data form sharedPrefs
   val storedUserName = sharedPref.getString("Some_key_user_name", defaultValue)
```

For the password, you can use the same approach. However, if the password is so precious(which it is in most cases) you can encrypt the data stored in sharedPreference file. Look ahead with [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data)

As an example in my `Activity`,

```kotlin
  val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return

   with (sharedPref.edit()) {
       putString("MY_HELLO_WORLD_KEY","helloWorld")
       commit()
   }
```

Comment: Can you show a simple example code for the above? Suppose i want to hardcode password 'helloWorld' in the app. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

- You can use key store to save your private keys securely

check this
[Securely Storing Keys in Android Keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298956/securely-storing-keys-in-android-keystore)

- you can also use [EncryptedPreferences](https://github.com/PDDStudio/EncryptedPreferences) to store simple data in an encrypted way.

check [How to save secret key securely in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698069/how-to-save-secret-key-securely-in-android)